# Multicurrency SOQL Query

Tags: soql, multi-currency

I am working in an org that has multi currency enabled, and am trying to query out the biggest opportunities per Account, where the opp is over 10,000 GBP or USD.

I was hoping to use something like this:

```
Select AccountId, MAX(Amount) FROM Opportunity WHERE Amount > USD10000 OR Amount > GBP10000 and CloseDate = LAST_N_YEARS:3 GROUP BY AccountId
```

If I query without specifying a currency, then the SOQL results are returned converting the amount to my locale. So I get USD 10,000 opportunities returned with the amount in GBP (which is around GBP£7k). Reason I need the true amount values, is I then want to loop over the values in apex to update some records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_currency_fields.htm) you can use it like that as long as you don't use it with aggregated results (so not `HAVING MAX(Amount) > GBP10000`)

So I'd say you can just have

```
SELECT AccountId, MAX(Amount)
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE 
    (Amount > USD10000 OR Amount > GBP10000) AND 
    CloseDate = LAST_N_YEARS:3 
GROUP BY AccountId
```

(note the difference in brackets)

Comment: Perfect thanks! I tried brackets myself, but was putting them in the wrong place, I had tried `... WHERE (Amount > USD10000) OR (Amount > GBP10000) AND CloseDate ...`